# Error in Mysql UPDATE query

Tags: php, mysql

I really don't understand why this query gives me an error in Mysql

```
UPDATE gallery_photos SET photo_title='Velato stupore' photo_link='http://path/to/img.jpg' WHERE photo_id='27'
```

phpmyadmin says:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near `'photo_link='http://path/to/im`

Comment: missing `,` on your query in the sets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a comma:

```
UPDATE gallery_photos SET photo_title='Velato stupore', photo_link='http://path/to/img.jpg' WHERE photo_id='27'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE gallery_photos SET photo_title='Velato stupore',photo_link='http://path/to/img.jpg' WHERE photo_id='27'
```

Use this

Answer (score 0):

It is a punctuation issue, you are missing comma between the columns to set

```
UPDATE gallery_photos SET photo_title='Velato stupore', photo_link='`http://path/to/img.jpg`' WHERE photo_id='27'
```